# Python 2.7 changing default browser for webbrower.open

Tags: python, python-2.7, browser, python-webbrowser

I am trying to open a page a wrote and saved to a local server. Everything is great but it defaults to opening in IE instead of Chrome. Chrome is my default browser and couldn't find any helpful tips online.

Sample code:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('192.168.1.254:1337/SmartFormTest1.php')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Alright, found the issue. My browser was correctly defaulted to chrome, the issue is the webbrowser.py file. Lines 539-563 read:

```
if sys.platform[:3] == "win":
class WindowsDefault(BaseBrowser):
    def open(self, url, new=0, autoraise=True):
        try:
            os.startfile(url)
        except WindowsError:
            # [Error 22] No application is associated with the specified
            # file for this operation: '<URL>'
            return False
        else:
            return True

_tryorder = []
_browsers = {}

# First try to use the default Windows browser
register("windows-default", WindowsDefault)

# Detect some common Windows browsers, fallback to IE
iexplore = os.path.join(os.environ.get("PROGRAMFILES", "C:\\Program Files"),
                        "Internet Explorer\\IEXPLORE.EXE")
for browser in ("firefox", "firebird", "seamonkey", "mozilla",
                "netscape", "opera", iexplore):
    if _iscommand(browser):
        register(browser, None, BackgroundBrowser(browse()
```

All I needed to do was add "chrome" to the list of for browser in (list).

Answer (score 1):

Following the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/webbrowser.html), there are a few directions you can go with this:

1. Set the environment variable `BROWSER`
2. Use `webbrowser.get('chrome')` to get a controller instance of Chrome, then use that to do your browsing
3. Check your setup -- are you positive that your default browser is set properly? Does it appear under the "Internet" icon in your Start menu?

Comment: 'webbrowser.get('chrome')' Or any other name, ('mozilla') for example, returns the following error:   File "C:\Python27\lib\webbrowser.py", line 52, in get
    raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser I also checked that Chrome was the default browser on my machine as well as on the server.

Comment: @user3681278 Do you have the same problem if you use `foo = webbrowser.Chrome(); foo.open(some_url)`?

Comment: Also, although it doesn't sound like it'll fix your problem, make sure you have `http://` at the beginning of your url.

Comment: Found the issue, see my posted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24044266/3681278

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, the following code works for me.

```
chrome_path = '"C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" %s'
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open('google.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

My browser was correctly defaulted to brave, just change it in the `webbrowser.py` file. `Lines 539-563`

In `Line 540`, just change the OS path to the desired browser you want to use. For Brave just change the path given to the iexplorer variable
like this:

```
iexplore = os.path.join(os.environ.get("PROGRAMFILES", "C:\\Program Files"),
                                "BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\Application\\brave.EXE")
```